# Is there a way to style SegmentPoints and Handles?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I need to style SegmentPoints and Handles with a different color. Not one which is using for `path.strokeColor` or `path.selectedColor`.

Also possible that I will need to change the size (or even shape) of SegmentPoints.

Is there a way to achieve this with current paper.js? Or maybe there are some tricks/hacks?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the style of the handle is to draw them manually. This is quite easy to do, just draw a line between handle points and a shape at those points.

Obviously, you would not need to select the paths if you draw custom handles: `path.selected = false;`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel that for SegmenPoint I will have to do the same. Create own shape and place them on SegmenPoints