# Paperjs problem with using custom paths as styling handles/segmentPoints

Tags: javascript, paperjs

[Example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

[Video Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fmAv.gif)

The **lack of selection styling** in paperjs makes you improvise and one way to style them, is to **create them yourself** ( recommended on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864574/is-there-a-way-to-style-segmentpoints-and-handles)).

But the huge con with this is the **performance!** Where canvas quickly goes from usable 60fps to terrible 20 within seconds. Now the only method I thought would work to style your handles/points, is now useless.

Now I'm out of ideas as to how style them and I'm trying to seek the help of stackoverflow... The main thing that I want to achieve is the hover effect on handles/points . At this point I coded the most of the stuff in paperjs, and I really wouldn't want to switch everything to something else like **PixiJs**.

P.S **Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

In your video, the frame rate goes down because you draw a lot of paths and this would also happen at some point even with the native Paper.js selection.

So your only chance is to try to have as few as possible shapes in your scene.
Maybe you can take advantage of the less known features of Paper.js to reduce them a bit:

- [item.selectedColor](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#selectedcolor)
- [paper.settings.handleSize](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#settings)

Then, there is also the possibility of using [SymbolItem](http://paperjs.org/reference/symbolitem/) for repeted shapes (like your circles) that should have better performances than regular paths.

Finally, if you're out of solutions, you could also fork the library and hook into the selection drawing code to adapt to your needs :).